# Cant eliminate zero

Tags: r, dataframe, na, zero

I have been trying to eliminate 0 in this data frame and tried all the methods here in stack overflow but none work!

this is the df

```
Department Hours   SIZE
1         HVAC  1281  38000
2           PH   717  38000
3          Ele   854  38000
4           LV   568  38000
5          Man   462  38000
7         HVAC   202  38000
8           PH    22  38000
9          Ele    30  38000
10          LV    49  38000
11         Man    75  38000
13        HVAC    52  33000
14          PH    40  33000
15         Ele    72  33000
16          LV     0  33000
17         Man     0  33000
19        HVAC   118  33000
```

I already tried these:

```
sizedf <- lapply(sizedf, function(x) x[x != 0 & !is.na(x)]) 

sizedf[sizedf$Hours==0] <- NA

sizedf[apply(sizedf[,-1], 1, function(x) !all(x== 0)),]
```

Comment: Do you want to remove the rows that contain 0 or replace it with NA?

Comment: Try `sizedf2 <- sizedf[!rowSums(sizedf[-1]==0),]`

Comment: @DavidArenburg My suggestion was based on the third line of code with `apply`

Comment: @akrun thats perfect thanks! post an answer so i can tick you!

Comment: @DavidArenburg I think the OP may need to use `any`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `rowSums` on the logical matrix created using the subset of dataset with the numeric columns and get a logical `vector` to subset the rows

```
sizedf2 <- sizedf[!rowSums(sizedf[-1]==0),]
```